# How to ignore -3.4028235e+38 as a minimum value in a DEM?

Tags: python, dem

I am working with a DEM with the range of 99.93-169.32 (This range can be seen in QGIS). I am trying to open this DEM using cv2 or rasterio in python, and after that apply some filtering methods to extract texture. Once I print the min and max values for this DEM, it changes the min value to “-3.4028235e+38”. If the DEM includes the “-3.4028235e+38” nodata value, the filtering operation produce some results with “inf” or “nan” pixel values. Can anyone suggest a way to ignore “-3.4028235e+38” and have the actual minimum value of 99.93?

```
arr_img= dem.read()
print(np.amin(arr_img))
print(np.amax(arr_img))

-3.4028235e+38
169.3008
```

---

Masked array result:

```
arr_msk=dem.read(masked=True)

masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
        [111.5587387084961, 111.62873840332031, 111.79273986816406, ...,
         142.4434814453125, 142.19747924804688, 141.91148376464844],
        [111.51673889160156, 111.58873748779297, 111.77873992919922, ...,
         142.469482421875, 142.2334747314453, 141.88548278808594],
        ...,
        [108.41439056396484, 108.43839263916016, 108.43238830566406, ...,
         122.17913818359375, 121.87313842773438, 122.0411376953125],
        [108.39238739013672, 108.38838958740234, 108.3683853149414, ...,
         122.39714050292969, 122.1391372680664, 122.15513610839844],
        [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --]],
  mask=[[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
        ...,
        [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]],
  fill_value=-3.4028235e+38,
  dtype=float32)
```

Comment: You probably need to use a package that is aware of No Data

Comment: I also tested gdal, and it recognizes -3.4028235e+38 as minimum value. Do you have a suggestion for a proper package?

Comment: Is the `NODATA` value correctly set up? what does `gdalinfo` say?

Comment: `dem.read(masked=True)`

Comment: @ user2856 Please see the update in the question. What should be done with the masked array?

Comment: @ Ian Turton After running ´gdalinfo -stat -hist /path to file/dem.tif ´, I got error: ´NameError: name 'gdalinfo'´ is not defined

Comment: `arr_img.min()`